# Turning off lighting effects for all layers using ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

Is it possible to turn off all lighting effects (ie to give simple 'flat' polygon fills, not shadowed/shaded) for ALL layers in a project?

I can only find this via the '3D effects' sub-menu tool which needs to set per layer >>> very tedious

Surely there is a way to disable all the lighting effects globally in ArcScene?

Answer (score 0):

...a possible 'workaround' > put all layers into a new group,then set group properties 'shade areal features..' to OFF.

This means setting per group if already groups exist, and/or removing new 'shade-groups' when finished with them .

Still cant find a simple 'Lighting-shade ON/OFF' global function for a whole project or scene....